# Extended ASCII character ° not working as a dictionary key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, encoding, character-encoding

For whatever the reason, I need a dictionary key with the character "°". The dictionary is declared the most straightforward way possible in a javascript file :

```js
var myDict = {
    "Angle °": 150
};
```

Unfortunately, when iterating over my elements and comparing the keys, the equality evaluation with this specific key doesn't work.

In Chrome console, showing the dictionary keys with `Object.Keys(myDict);` shows this key with a specific question mark � instead of °.

However, when the dictionary is created the exact same way, directly in the Chrome console, everything is working well, that's why I cannot give an example snippet.

I have tried both this solutions :

- Adding `charset = "UTF-8"` to the `<script>` tag.
- Adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `<head>`.

Comment: What `Content-Type` header is the Javascript file served with by the server…?

Comment: You mean the `type` property ? `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @TitouanL - I think deceze meant what he asked ... the Content-Type in the header of the javascript file when the server sends it - assuming the script is not inline script

Comment: Look at the browser's developer tools' network inspector, and see the response headers of that particular Javascript file.

Comment: @deceze it's `application/javascript; charset=utf-8`

Comment: And the file is *actually* saved as UTF-8?

Comment: I have no idea how to make sure of that, but as the duplicate question states, using `\u00B0` solves the problem. My bad english is at fault, didn't know how to search for °, which is called Degree Unicode.

Comment: You need to actually save the file as UTF-8 in your text editor/IDE. How to do that exactly will depend on the exact program in question.

Comment: @deceze Oh wow, I had no clue this was a thing. Changed the encoding on the bottom right corner of PyCharm, thank you very much !

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)